# gRPC Name Resolution Failure

Tags: docker, tensorflow-serving, grpc-python

While trying to run tensorflow-serving with docker, I am getting the following error issuing a client request using gRPC with following code:

```
`python client.py --server=172.17.0.2/16:9000 --image=./test_images/image2.jpg

debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1551888435.208113000","description":"Failed to create subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":2267,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1551888435.208109000","description":"Name resolution failure","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/request_routing.cc","file_line":165,"grpc_status":14}]}"`
```

Information about my environment:

> OS: macOS virtual env.: Anaconda 3 Python 3.6 gRPC/tools 1.19

Would you please help me in resolving the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the channel is in TRANSIENT_FAILURE and the load balancing policy can't find any ready backend to send the request.

Please file an issue on https://github.com/grpc/grpc/ detailing what you did, hopefully with more log/tracing context, so that we can better help you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I just issued it in github: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/18290#issue-418220230

Answer (score 0):

The IP Address, `172.17.0.2/16`, which looks slightly different seems to cause the problem. You can use `localhost` instead.

So, the command for running the `client.py` can be

```
python client.py --server=localhost:9000 --image=./test_images/image2.jpg
```